# Stopping a Laravel Queue after it has finished running

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, supervisord, laravel-queue

I am running a web application on Laravel 5.5. I have a requirement to run the jobs in a queue and then stop the queue. The queue cannot be allowed to stay running.

I am running the below command but this just endlessly carries on.

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

If I use supervisord can I stop the queue from inside the Laravel application.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Seems jank but i'd be curious if you could call the queue:restart artisan command  ```Artisan::call('queue:restart');``` or queuing it, ```Artisan::queue('queue:restart');```. No clue if that would work, just shooting from the hip. Without supervisor or something running, it should force the workers to "die gracefully" in theory™

Comment: In theory `php artisan queue:work --once` will just process one job, but if you're triggering this as part of a request you might as well just be using the sync queue instead

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Processing All Queued Jobs & Then Exiting 
> The `--stop-when-empty option` may be used to instruct the worker to process all jobs and then exit gracefully. This option can be useful when working Laravel queues within a Docker container if you wish to shutdown the container after the queue is empty:

Try `php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --stop-when-empty`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Comment: don't think that option is available in 5.5

Comment: beh, i didn't even notice the mentioned version number, you're right

Comment: yes Laravel 5.5 does not have that command available